# Replacing characters in powershell without use of quotes

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, vifm

This situation has come about through limitations in vifm (a vim-based file browser), but the question is really about the windows command line and powershell.

In vifm I have implemented the following command:

```
:execute 'goto' fnameescape(term('powershell -Command " & {Get-ChildItem -Recurse | % { $_.FullName.Replace('\','/') }}" | fzf'))
```

it sends the command:

```
powershell -Command " & {Get-ChildItem -Recurse | % { $_.FullName.Replace('\','/') }}" | fzf
```

to the windows command-line (cmd.exe), which generates a list of the full paths of all files and folders in the current directory and sub directories, replaces and backslashes with forward slashes (required by vifm's `goto` command) and pipes it to fzf, where one of these lines can then be selected and is sent to vifm.

Running this command from cmd.exe works perfectly, as does running

```
:execute 'goto' fnameescape(term('powershell -Command " & {Get-ChildItem -Recurse | % { $_.FullName }}" | fzf'))
```

through vifm.

The problem I'm having is with the Replace statement since this requires either single or double quotes and I'm already using single quotes to encapsulate the entire cmd.exe argument in vifm, and double quotes to encapsulate the entire powershell command in cmd.exe.

Could anyone suggest a way this can be implemented in one line whilst avoiding this restriction, such that it can be run from vifm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could anyone suggest a way this can be implemented in one line whilst avoiding this restriction, such that it can be run from `vifm`?

The best strategy here may be to eliminate the need for "extra" quotes in your `:execute` statement by simply running the desired PowerShell command as a separate `.ps1` script:

*ex. fuzzy_finder.ps1*

```
& {Get-ChildItem -Recurse | % { $_.FullName.Replace('\','/') }} | fzf
```

You should be then able to use something like the following in `vifm`:

```
:execute 'goto' fnameescape(term('powershell fuzzy_finder.ps1'))
```

One important thing to note is that the `powershell fuzzy_finder.ps1` syntax assumes that the ex. `fuzzy_finder.ps1` script is "globally" available (i.e. it resides in a folder that is also in your Path).

---

*Note that I might suggest using `ForEach` in place of `%` e.g.*:

```
& {Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach { $_.FullName.Replace('\','/') }} | fzf
```

*as suggested in the other answer to this question. While it doesn't seem to make much of a difference in this case, `ForEach` may be more "robust" is terms of alleviating potential PowerShell execution issues broadly.*

---

Comment: Thanks. This is actually the solution I've been using, but it breaks portability so I was hoping there'd be an alternative. I'll keep the question open for now, but if it seems there's in fact no way of doing this I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Also worth noting that there's a difference between having '| fzf' within the ps1 script and outside it; if fzf is executed by cmd it will update with the output from powershell in real time (but require a Ctrl+c if fzf exits first), which is likely preferable. If it's executed within powershell it'll wait for the first command to complete (which can take some time depending on the number of files scanned).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
:execute 'goto' fnameescape(term('powershell -Command {Get-ChildItem -Recurse ^| ForEach { $_.FullName.Replace("\","/") }} | fzf'))
```

Comment: The double quotes are required by cmd.exe, else when it hits the pipe it starts executing the next command instead of passing it all to powershell, so you get the error from cmd.exe: '%' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Edited the code please check

Comment: Thanks, but now cmd is just trying to execute ForEach instead, so I get the error: 'ForEach' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Again escaped it by caret please check.

Comment: This is now all sent to powershell but isn't passed properly by powershell. It returns the error from powershell: The string is missing the terminator: ". + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString